# unity EditorWindow#Focus cannot trigger EditorWindow#OnGUI

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

here is my code:

```
public class RoEditorWindow : EditorWindow
{
    private static RoEditorWindow win;

    [MenuItem("Window/Ro Editor Window %g")]
    static void St()
    {
        if (!win)
        {
            win = EditorWindow.GetWindow<RoEditorWindow>();
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Run focus");
            win.Focus();
        }
    }

    private void OnGUI()
    {
        var ev = Event.current;
        if (ev.isKey )
        {
            Debug.Log("key is pressed");
        }
    }
}
```

see my gifs, when i click my win and hit shortcut "ctrl+g", console will output "run focus" and "key is pressed"
[image]

but if i click other win(to make my win lost focus) and hit shortcut "ctrl+g" to focus win, console only output "run focus", "key is pressed" in OnGUI cannot be called
[image]
so how to focus EditorWindow in script to make OnGUI work after focus

Answer (score 1):

this problem is because I focus **floating** editorwindow, if I drag my win make it as **tab** editorwindow(see my gif), EditorWindow#Focus work well

[image]

if I really wanna use floating win

here is my solution, use EditorWindow#ShowAuxWindow and EditorWindow#titleContent to create editorwindow with title that include current project unity editor process id

and use os focus window code to focus this win, in linux I can use xdotool, in windows, i guess win32 api can do it, I think mac has similar way

here is my unity editor for linux solution:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;
using Debug = UnityEngine.Debug;

public class RoEditorWindow : EditorWindow
{
    private static RoEditorWindow win;

    [MenuItem("Window/Ro Editor Window %g")]
    static void St()
    {
        if (!win)
        {
            win = ScriptableObject.CreateInstance<RoEditorWindow>();
        }

        Debug.Log("Run Focus");
        win.ShowAuxWindow();
        EditorWindow.FocusWindowIfItsOpen<RoEditorWindow>();
        var title = $"Ro Editor Windows in Process {Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id}";
        win.SetTitle(title);
        new Thread(() =>
        {
            var startAt = DateTime.Now;
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    var cmd = $"xdotool search --name --onlyvisible --limit  1 \"{title}\"";
                    var wid = Sh(cmd);
                    if (wid != "")
                    {
                        Sh($"xdotool windowactivate {wid}");
                        break;
                    }
                }
                catch (SystemException e)
                {
                }

                if ((DateTime.Now - startAt).TotalSeconds > 5)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }).Start();
    }

    public static string Sh(string cmd)
    {
        string output = "";
        string error = string.Empty;

        var psi = new ProcessStartInfo("/bin/bash", $"-c '{cmd}'");

        psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        psi.RedirectStandardError = true;
        psi.UseShellExecute = false;
        Process p = Process.Start(psi);
        using (System.IO.StreamReader myOutput = p.StandardOutput)
        {
            output = myOutput.ReadToEnd();
        }

        using (System.IO.StreamReader myError = p.StandardError)
        {
            error = myError.ReadToEnd();
        }

        if (error != "")
        {
            throw new SystemException($"err cmd: {cmd}\n{error}");
        }

        return output;
    }


    public void SetTitle(string v)
    {
        titleContent = new GUIContent(v);
    }

    private void OnGUI()
    {
        EditorGUILayout.TextField("input", "");
        if (Event.current.isKey)
        {
            Debug.Log("key is pressed");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am about to put an answer because this works on Linux only

Answer (score 0):

Your current code should work. Tested it on my side and it worked fine. I will just assume that this is a bug within the Editor.

The workaround for detecting key press even when a Window is not focused is to use subscribe to the `EditorApplication.globalEventHandler` event. Unfortunately, this function is marked as `internal` so you can't access it directly but you can use reflection to access it. This should work on any platform that supports the Editor.

In the example below, you will get a log when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>.

```
public class RoEditorWindow : EditorWindow
{
    private static RoEditorWindow win;
    EditorApplication.CallbackFunction appCb;

    [MenuItem("Window/Ro Editor Window %g")]
    static void St()
    {
        if (!win)
        {
            win = EditorWindow.GetWindow<RoEditorWindow>();
        }
        else
        {

            Debug.Log("Run focus");
            win.Focus();
        }
    }

    void OnEnable()
    {
        EnableInputEvent();
    }

    void OnDisable()
    {
        DisableInputEvent();
    }

    void EnableInputEvent()
    {
        FieldInfo fieldInfo = typeof(EditorApplication).GetField("globalEventHandler", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        appCb = (EditorApplication.CallbackFunction)fieldInfo.GetValue(null);
        appCb += OnEditorKeyPress;
        fieldInfo.SetValue(null, appCb);
    }

    void DisableInputEvent()
    {
        FieldInfo fieldInfo = typeof(EditorApplication).GetField("globalEventHandler", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        appCb -= OnEditorKeyPress;
        fieldInfo.SetValue(null, appCb);
    }
    private void OnEditorKeyPress()
    {
        var ev = Event.current;
        if (ev.control && ev.type == EventType.KeyDown && ev.keyCode == KeyCode.G)
        {
            Debug.Log("key is pressed");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work, see https://imgur.com/a/kcd3V2u, I think it's unity linux editor 2017.4.10 bug or linux mint xfce4 bug, unity linux editor has many focus bug in linux, and most case I can fix it with `xdotool`, so I think my code is right but it doesn't work in unity linux editor

Comment: I know your code is right and considered this a bug on Linux. I put this as a workaround which is sad because it's not working too. Although, it should work on Windows and possibly Mac